# Making a generic web API controller when using multiple tables with similar fields

Tags: c#, mvc, generics, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api

I have been trying to refactor my code since I found I've been doing a lot of copying and pasting to implement the logic of the web API controllers. Here's how the controllers looked like before refactoring

Controller for `EducationalGroups` table:

```
public class EducationalGroupsController : ApiController
    {
        public HttpResponseMessage Get()
        {
            try
            {
                using (SchoolDbContext entities = new SchoolDbContext())
                    return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK,
                        entities.EducationGroups.Where(g => !g.Is_Delete).ToList());
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                return Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.NoContent, e);
            }
        }

        public HttpResponseMessage Post([FromBody] EducationGroup group)
        {
            try
            {
                using (SchoolDbContext entities = new SchoolDbContext())
                {
                    group.Create_User = WebApiConfig.CurrUserIdx;
                    group.Create_Date = DateTime.Now;

                    entities.EducationGroups.Add(group);
                    entities.SaveChanges();

                    var msg = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.Created, group);
                    msg.Headers.Location = new Uri(Request.RequestUri, group.Id.ToString());
                    return msg;
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                return Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, e);
            }
        }
    }
```

Controller for `EducationalStages` table:

```
public class EducationalStagesController : ApiController
    {
        public HttpResponseMessage Get()
        {
            try
            {
                //Notice the only difference here is the *Educational_Stages* object of type DbSet
                using (SchoolDbContext entities = new SchoolDbContext())
                    return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, 
                        entities.Education_Stages.Where(s => !s.Is_Delete).ToList());
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                return Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.NoContent, e);
            }
        }

        //Same implementation for this method as previous controller 
        //Only with the difference of the type of the parameter
        public HttpResponseMessage Post([FromBody] Education_Stages stage)
        {
            try
            {
                using (SchoolDbContext entities = new SchoolDbContext())
                {
                    stage.Create_User = WebApiConfig.CurrUserIdx;
                    stage.Create_Date = DateTime.Now;

                    entities.Education_Stages.Add(stage);
                    entities.SaveChanges();

                    var msg = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.Created, stage);
                    msg.Headers.Location = new Uri(Request.RequestUri, stage.Id.ToString());
                    return msg;
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                return Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, e);
            }
        }
    }
```

There are like 8 more controllers required for 8 more tables, so you get the idea of how redundant it looks like...

What I've been trying to do is create a base class for the entities that share the same fields as follows:

```
public abstract class BaseEntity
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }

        [StringLength(50)]
        public string Ar_Name { get; set; }

        [StringLength(10)]
        public string En_Name { get; set; }

        public bool Is_Delete { get; set; }

        public int? Create_User { get; set; }

        public DateTime? Create_Date { get; set; }

        public int? Last_Update_User { get; set; }

        public DateTime? Last_Update_Date { get; set; }
    }
```

And inherit it in all of the entities sharing the same fields:

```
public partial class Education_Stages : BaseEntity
    {
    }
```

And then create a base class for the API controllers to inherit from as follows, and here's where I can't find any more solutions for what I want:

```
public abstract class BaseApiVerbs<T> : ApiController where T : BaseEntity
    {
        private DbSet<T> dbSet;

        public BaseApiVerbs(DbSet<T> _dbSet)
        {
            dbSet = _dbSet;
        }

        public HttpResponseMessage Get()
        {
            try
            {
                return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, 
                    dbSet.Where(t => t.Is_Delete == false));
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                return Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, e);
            }
        }
        public HttpResponseMessage Post([FromBody] T entity)
        {
            // No Idea how to implement the same logic here without using DbContext... 
        }
```

Furthermore, I don't know how to initialize the controllers' classes and pass the `DbSet` object accordingly:

```
public class CityController : BaseApiVerbs<City>
    {
        SchoolDbContext context = new SchoolDbContext();
        public CityController() 
            : base( /* How would I pass the DbSet object here? */ )
        {
            
        }
    }
```

Is the idea of copying and pasting the code acceptable in this case? If not, how can I accomplish what I've been trying to do for the past two days?

I am a beginner so please don't be harsh in your replies if you found anything smelly in my code, kindly note it for me :)

Comment: Do I understand correctly that the refactored version is not complete?

Comment: A good start would be to go use dependency injection. If this is .net core, a DI framework is readily available.

Answer (score 1):

Honestly, don't try to invent new ways of doing things and instead learn well-documented ways of doing things, like [MediatR](https://github.com/jbogard/MediatR) and [CQRS](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/using-mediator-in-web-apis-for-cqrs-pattern/).

Please follow the Microsoft guidelines when naming things: only alphanumeric characters are allowed in property names, class names etc. (exception is the underscore at the start of a private member variable).

Use readable names. `Ar_Name` and `En_Name` are meaningless. `Create_User` and the likes are names of methods, not properties.